# Kafka: Number of Partitions are more than no of broker

Tags: apache-kafka

I have following questions regarding Kafka:

1. If I create a topic and specify no of partitions more than no of brokers, then a single broker will handle more than 1 partition?
2. If I create a topic and specify replication factor more than no of brokers, will the topic create or not?
3. Can a single broker will handle multiple partitions of different topic.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

1. That is correct. If you have more partitions than available brokers, then some of your brokers will store more than one partition per topic. For example, let's assume you have one alive broker and a topic with two partitions; Your broker will look like below:

```
    +-------------------+
    |      Topic X      |
    |    Partition 0    |
    |                   |
    |                   |
    |     Topic X       |
    |   Partition 1     |
    +-------------------+
```

2. No, it is not possible to create topic with higher replication factor than the available brokers. If you attempt to do it you will get an error. For example, let's say you are trying to create a topic with `--replication-factor 3` and only one available broker:

```
>> bin/kafka-topics.sh --create --zookeeper localhost:2181 --replication-factor 3 --partitions 1 --topic myTestTopic

Error while executing topic command replication factor: 3 larger than available
brokers: 1
kafka.admin.AdminOperationException: replication factor: 3 larger than available
 brokers: 1
        at kafka.admin.AdminUtils$.assignReplicasToBrokers(AdminUtils.scala:70)
        at kafka.admin.AdminUtils$.createTopic(AdminUtils.scala:171)
        at kafka.admin.TopicCommand$.createTopic(TopicCommand.scala:93)
        at kafka.admin.TopicCommand$.main(TopicCommand.scala:55)
        at kafka.admin.TopicCommand.main(TopicCommand.scala)
```

3. Definitely. Let's say you have only 2 brokers and 3 topics each of which has 2 partitions with a `replication-factor=1`. An example overview of your brokers is shown below:

```
    +-------------------+
    |      Topic 1      |
    |    Partition 0    |
    |                   |
    |                   |
    |     Topic 3       |
    |   Partition 1     |
    |                   |
    |                   |
    |     Topic 2       |
    |   Partition 1     |
    +-------------------+


    +-------------------+
    |      Topic 1      |
    |    Partition 1    |
    |                   |
    |                   |
    |     Topic 3       |
    |   Partition 0     |
    |                   |
    |                   |
    |     Topic 2       |
    |   Partition 0     |
    +-------------------+
```

Comment: In the first Case, which partition will be the leader, and how a producer send data if multiple partitions of  the same topic exist because according to Kafka 

**The producer can only send data to the broker that is the leader of a partition.**

So in that case we are only able to send data to 1 partition only in case one broker has many partition for same topic

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes, a broker can handle numerous partitions on multiple topics. There is an overhead to having more partitions, so choosing the "right" number requires knowledge of many factors.
2. I think the topic *may* create but you will struggle to write to it, possibly thnere are a couple of outcomes depending on exact set up.
3. Absolutely!

Good luck :D